# Алгоритм генерации самого длинного палиндрома из строки

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

На вход функции подается строка, которая может иметь мощность до 10^5 символов. Необходимо из это строки составить максимально длинный палиндром/палиндромы и вернуть тот, который лексикографически минимальный. Первое что я сделал, это хэш и отсортированный список уникальных букв:
ключи - буквы, значения - количество букв. Чтобы было понятнее ниже пример:

```
st = 'aaabbb'
hash_char = {'a':3, 'b':3} # Это легко было сделать, помог Counter from collections
sorted_char = ['a', 'b']
```

Прежде чем писать сюда, я гуглил. В основном я находил алгоритм нахождения самого длинного палиндрома подстроки.
Далее, так как мне нужно вернуть лексикографический минимум из самых длинных палиндромов.
Ниже код, который отрабатывает. Но хотелось бы уменьшить ее сложность

```
from collections import Counter


def all_palindromes(string: str):
    hash_chars = Counter(string)
    res = ''
    sorted_chars = sorted(hash_chars.keys())
    for char in sorted_chars:
        for i in range(hash_chars[char] // 2):
            res += char
            hash_chars[char] -= 2

    for char in sorted_chars:
        if hash_chars[char]:
            return res + char + res[::-1]

    return res + res[::-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    st1 = 'aaabbb'
    st2 = 'aaabbbb' 
    print(all_palindromes(st1)) # ababa (Тут все хорошо)
    print(all_palindromes(st2)) # abbabba (Тут тоже вроде хорошо)
```

Решение тесты прошло. Как можно уменьшить сложность этого решения?

Comment: Вы правильно говорите. Я текст исправил. Нужно было вернуть именно минимальный лексикографический

Comment: вам надо уменьшить сложность кода лексикографического сравнения или поиска полиномов? и еще - составить полиндром из строки - это выделить из строки или на основе доступных символов составить?

Comment: Общую сложность хочу понизить. Может уже существуют какие-то иные, более оптимальные по сложности алгоритмы, а я тут придумываю свою.

Comment: так полином внутри строки содержится или строка - это всего лишь набор символов чтобы составить полином?

Comment: Строка - это всего лишь набор символов. Тут не полином, а палиндром.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложность O(n*lon n) из за сортировки, но можно выполнить сортировку подсчетом, если набор символов ограничить до ascii, тогда будет O(n)

```
def all_palindromes2(string: str):
    freq = sorted(Counter(string).items())
    half = ''.join(n // 2 * x for x, n in freq)
    middle = next((x for x, n in freq if n % 2 == 1), '')
    return half + middle + half[::-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

вот такой код должен быть?

основной принцип - сначала используем символы, которые имеют более низкое лексикографическое значение, в центре ставим тоже символ с наиболее низким лексикографическим значением

```
# получить строку
text = input()

# подсчитать символы из строки:
letters = dict()
for letter in 'аАбБвВгГдДеЕёЁжЖзЗиИкКлЛмМнНоОпПрРсСтТуУфФхХцЦчЧшШщЩьЬыЫъЪэЭюЮяЯ':
    letters[letter] = 0

for letter in text:
    letters[letter] = letters[letter] + 1

# собрать палиндром с минимальным лексикографическим значением
border_part = ''
middle_part = ''

for key in letters:
    if letters[key] == 0:
        continue

    border_part = border_part + key * (letters[key] // 2)

    if letters[key] % 2 == 1 and middle_part == '':
        middle_part = key

# собрать палиндром
result = border_part + middle_part + border_part[::-1]

print(result)
```